# How to reduce the time between screenshot of widget and saving screenshot as byte array?

Tags: qt, qt5

I am making a screenshot of a widget and save it as byte array so that I can send the 10 screenshots to a client through tcp socket in 1 second. What should I do to reduce the time of saving screenshot as byte array or is any other ways to solve my problem?

When tested 100K screenshot with the following code in Qt5, I found pixmap.save() method spend more than 100ms which too much time wasting. I have tried a lot but still not find a appropriate way to both do my job and save time.

```
QPixmap pixmap = QWidget::grab(); 
QByteArray bytes; 
QBuffer buffer(&bytes); 
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly); 
pixmap.save(&buffer, "JPG");
```

Comment: What's your minimum transfer rate? What's the image resolution? How long does grab take? JPG encoding is relatively expensive, have you considered using another image format with a better ratio of encoding speed to output size?

Comment: @replete I want to transer 10 frames in 1 second. Widget.grab() spends about 20ms when making a 100K JPG screenshot. I also tested saving as PNG and it generated 1M data which spend about 1 second during pixmap.save() called. I think the picture should be as small as possible to ensure to reduce the whole time.

Comment: By minimum transfer rate I referred to the data connection. How many bytes per second is your guaranteed minimum? Again what is the resolution of the image, width x height? These calculations must be done first, to work out whether the problem is realistic.

Comment: I hope this isn't an x-y problem, by the way. At any rate, another possibility is to roll your own grab (check https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html search for ::grab to see how they do it), and draw the grab to a QImage rather than a QPixmap. That gives you access to the raw pixel data. That would enable you to compress it yourself giving you more control over the process.  This assumes you have control over the receiver too. The problem remains underspecified.

Comment: @replete Sorry I can't understrand what is minimum transfer rate. Do you mean bitrate or bandwidth? The resolution of the image is 1440x900. And the grab() is a member function of QWidget. I will try to find a way to use QImage directly.